# HTML field once invalidated is not validating again

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have an `Input` element in my form. I have applied validity on it that it must contains 10 digits. I done it using `min and max` values. The element is

```
<form action="" method="post">  
    <input class="form-control required" id="id_phone" max="9999999999" min="1000000000" name="phone" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter a 10 DIgits Valid Mobile Number')" onvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')" required="required" title="Enter a 10 DIgits Mobile Number" type="number">
</form>
```

The validations are working fine. It is not accepting a value having lesser than 10 digits. But the problem is that if i entered a wrong value in it once and try to submit form it shows me validation error, but it shows me validation error again if i put the right value or 10 digits value in it.

If i put correct or  10 digits value first time and try to submit the form then it works fine.

Comment: Kindly share your JS code

Comment: I didn't write any js code. It is html5 validations

Comment: Just remove `onvalid` and put a condition inside `setCustomValidity`. Which will show error or skip depending on the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u use patterns?

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Example:

```html
<form action="" method="post">  
    <input class="form-control required" id="id_phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="phone"  required="required" title="Enter a 10 DIgits Mobile Number" type="tel">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems working, but i want to change the error message. I want to remove the messgae ` Please match the requested format:` into the message.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `onvalid` attribute works in HTML5. Because the message will be alerted only if the validation fails. Otherwise it will not.

I think this is what you want.

```
<form action="" method="post">  
    <input class="form-control required" id="id_phone" max="9999999999" min="1000000000" name="phone" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Enter a 10 DIgits Valid Mobile Number')" required="required" title="Enter a 10 DIgits Mobile Number" type="number">
</form>
```

I hope this helps you!

EDIT: Run the following code directly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">  
    <input class="form-control required" id="id_phone" max="9999999999" min="1000000000" name="phone" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Enter a 10 DIgits Valid Mobile Number')" required="required" title="Enter a 10 DIgits Mobile Number" type="number">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i removed the `onvalid` attribute and added `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Enter a 10 DIgits Valid Mobile Number')"`. but in error message it says `Please enter a value greater than or equal to 1000000000`.